# Missing axis values in plotting of NetCDF variable in group with xarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am constructing a NetCDF file that will be used with `xarray`. It will consist of many groups that use dimensions that are defined in the root group. In my current example, `xarray`'s `plot` function is unable to put the  proper values on the axes. Tools like `panoply` or `ncview` produce plots that do put the proper values of the dimensions at the axes. The script below creates a file which allows me to reproduce the problem. Do I construct the NetCDF file in an incorrect way, or is this a bug in `xarray`?

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Three series, two variables that contain the axis values and the 2D field.
z = np.arange(0., 1000., 50.)
time = np.arange(0., 86400., 3600.)
a = np.random.rand(time.size, z.size)

# The two dimensions are stored in the root group.
nc_file = nc.Dataset("test.nc", mode="w", datamodel="NETCDF4", clobber=False)
nc_file.createDimension("z"   , z.size   )
nc_file.createDimension("time", time.size)

nc_z    = nc_file.createVariable("z"   , "f8", ("z")   )
nc_time = nc_file.createVariable("time", "f8", ("time"))
nc_z   [:] = z   [:]
nc_time[:] = time[:]

# The 2D field is created and stored in a group called test_group.
nc_group = nc_file.createGroup("test_group")

nc_a = nc_group.createVariable("a", "f8", ("time", "z"))
nc_a[:,:] = a[:,:]

nc_file.close()

# Opening the file in x-array shows a plot that misses the axes values.
xr_file = xr.open_dataset("test.nc", "test_group")
xr_a = xr_file['a']
xr_a.plot()
plt.show()
```

The resulting figure, which has just the count rather than the dimension values on the axes, is:
[image: Resulting plot]